# Getting warning for transition View Controller and App Crashed

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, terminate

When I've tried to open detail view (using didSelectRowAtIndex) from ListViewController getting warning like
**Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.** and after app get crashed with error -**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't add self as subview'**
Any Help will be appreciated thanks..

MY App Hierarchy is

- UIWindow

  - UITabBarController

    - UINavigationController

      - UIViewController

Can any one tell me What is reason why I'm getting waring ?(Sorry For my English)

**UPDATE**

Here is My Code for DetailController

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
XXXInfo *dInfo=[_SDArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
DetailViewController *detail1=[DetailViewController viewControllerWithInfo:dInfo];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detail1 animated:YES];
}
```

//static Method to Navigate to Detail

```
 +(DetailViewController *)viewControllerWithInfo:(XXXInfo *)info
 {
   DetailViewController *detail=[[DetailViewController  alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
   detail.detailInfo=info;
   NSLog(@"info%@ ",info);
   return detail;
}
```

[image: Please Look at My App Hierarchy]

Comment: Add your code in didSelectRowAtIndex

Comment: I've updated my Question .. @trick14 please look at this

Comment: Are you doing anything with the NavigationControllers navigationBar?

Comment: No I'm doing nothing with navigation bar yet @theMonster

Comment: It looks ok. What kind of the class you deleted on the screenshot? Any modification on UINavigationController?

Comment: I just had remove my original navigation controller class name.. @trick14

Comment: @trick  you should not ask OP to show(Class,Controller Name) everything,it's not necessary. it's visible and any one can easily understand

Comment: Any one can help me??

Comment: Could you tell me what will "viewControllerWithInfo" method do?

Comment: @sonNguyen Static method its looks like +(DetailViewController*)viewControllerWithInfo:(XXXInfo*)info

Comment: @sonNguyen I've updated my code again.. Please help me out some one

Comment: Can anybody answer to my question?

Comment: Hi, Code looks ok, however if you want to push a view into navigation stack when a row is selected, you should set animated:NO at deselectRowAtIndexPath or should not use that line of code, because animation needs a duration to run, this may cause the conflict.

Comment: I need adequate answer..Could any one help me with this?

Comment: Hi, let's set [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO] in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method and try to run your app :)

Comment: @sonNguyen thanks.. it really helped me... but what do you think is this really good or better (permanent)solution, What if my client would to keep animation as well?

Comment: Hi, it's up to you, if you want to keep the animation, you can split lines of code to push viewController into a small method, then use "performSelector" to execute that method after about 1 second. I will post my response as an answer, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Animation to deselect the selected row needs a short period to animate then it causes the conflict, there are 2 ways to solve this problem:

1. Set animated:NO
   [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO]
2. Move lines of code to push detail view into a small method, then use performSelector to execute that method after about 1->1.5 second.